# Facebook app submission failed

Tags: ios, facebook, publish-actions

I am developing an iOS app in which I uses Facebook.I have submitted my app for Facebook review for publish_actions permission. But it got rejected due to the following reason.

> We could not reproduce the requested permission. Please submit a timeline screenshot of a successful publish on Facebook, as well as detailed, step-by-step English instructions in the "Add Notes" section of the permission.

Here,I don't understand where to submit a screenshots of successful publish?

Where can I submit the screenshots of successful publish on Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API allows third-party apps to integrate deeply with Facebook. Your app needs to be submitted again with required screenshots they asked.

I think this link will be helpful for you. Please ignore, if you have already seen this.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook review team strictly followed these rules.**

1. **1.You have to give a clear instruction for the user.(why you are asking the permission in add notes  part)
   2.Image resolution.**

> for your reference, refer the following links

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process

http://twocentstudios.com/blog/2014/07/05/my-review-of-the-new-facebook-login-review-process/

,

Comment: I just wanted to know where should i provide the screenshots of successful publish on timeline. I have submitted screenshots of app at the time of submission,Do I have to submit there or in add note section?